# Tomcat6 does not restart geoserver

Tags: java, geoserver, catalina

I've been using geoserver for a while, and it suddenly stopped working.
I usually restart it by relaunching tomcat6:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 stop

sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
```

I often had to do that because geoserver GWC process was using too much memory.
But this times it refuses to restart.
I had a look to the geoserver.log: it actual starts, load layers, and the last line is:

2014-12-11 16:44:53,765 WARN [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter] - Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'geoServerLoader': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'GWCLifeCycleHandler': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)

Is it possibly the error preventing geoserver to start?
If yes, can someone interpret this error message for me, and give a possible solution?

Note: 
I tried to remove files in geowebcache, but I still have the problem /geowebcache_data/diskquota_page_store_h2
I restarted the server too.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem:
I simply deleted the tomcat6 working directory: `$TOMCAT_HOME/work/Catalina` 
To do that:

1. stop tomcat: /etc/init.d/tomcat6 stop
2. delete the working directory `$TOMCAT_HOME/work/Catalina` . Of course, double check you are in the working directory and not in Catalina application directory!
3. restart tomcat: /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
   IT may take a while as it must rebuild the temporary directory. In my case, it did not restart, and I could see that tomcat was not restarted and a PID was already existing (using the command `/etc/init.d/tomcat6 status`). I simply rebooted my server, to have the pid lock released.